# C++ returning non const reference out of const object

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, const-correctness

I have structure that contains reference in it

```
template <class T>
struct RefContainer {

    RefContainer(T& t) : _r(t) {}

    T& getRef() {
        return _r;
    }

private:
    T& _r;
};
```

Now, another object, which is immutable uses this structure inside itself and has this object in it like so:

```
RefContainer<char> _c;
```

When I use that immutable object to transform itself with a dot I get a const reference. Since I call getRef of RefContainer object inside the immutable objects compiler says I violate const correctness.

The RefContainer itself has to hold non-const lvalue reference but I'd love to chain calls on immutable object to create new ones like so:

```
ImmubableObject obj;
auto newObj = obj.copyWithSomeAttributes().modifyWithThisString("str");
// I'm on C++11 btw, so I can use everything C++11 has to offer
```

How do I work this out the "right" way (possibly avoiding ugly const casts) ?

Comment: add a `const` version or overload if need to have the same name (`const T& getConstRef() const { return _r }`) and use this in cases you don't want to change `returned T&`

Comment: @avakar That would be terrible.

Comment: @Jefffrey, no, there's a reason why const is not transitive with regards to pointers and references.

Comment: @avakar What are you on about?

Comment: What does it mean that `ImmubableObject` is immutable? Does it mean that it's a typedef to some `const T`?

Comment: @Jefffrey - not exactly. It means, when I create this object it's fields were never meant to change and the only way you can get different versions of that object is create new ones with different fields.

Comment: @VanillaFace Can I see the definition of that class?

Comment: If `ImmumableObject` is really supposed to be immutable, it should be `ImmumableObject const obj;`   (probably withs ome constructor arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
template <class T>
struct RefContainer {

    RefContainer(T& t) : _r(t) {}

    T& getRef() const {
             // ^^^^^
        return _r;
    }

private:
    T& _r;
};
```

This way, the `T&` reference can be used as non const, regardless the `RefContainer` instance is a `const` object or not.

Comment: You don't need that `mutable`. In fact, it's not allowed.

Comment: @T.C. I wasn't sure about it, and actually didn't try out the code. I see, changing a reference won't be allowed anyways.

Comment: I'm not sure this is ok. You are effectively breaking const-correctness.

Comment: @Jefffrey That would be the case if it was returning a reference to a data member.

Comment: @Jefffrey _"You are effectively breaking const-correctness."_ No I don't. If `RefContainer` would hold a `const T& _r;` yes. But actually it just wraps a (non const!) reference, nothing more nothing less. Correct state handling is left to the reference, not to the container.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "But actually it just wraps a (non const!) reference". So the semantic of `RefContainer` is the same of `T&`. But the semantic of `const RefContainer` is not the same as `const T&`.

Comment: The solution to this argument is that OP needs to specify whether a `const RefContainer` is supposed to wrap a const reference. It seems to me that his post specifies that it is supposed to contain non-const references.

Comment: @Jefffrey Semantical issues should address for actual use cases, which aren't clearly stated from the OP. Syntactically it's perfectly valid to hand out non const references from const class/struct instances.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What do you mean?

Comment: @Jefffrey _"What do you mean?"_ What are you arguing about?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't understand what you mean by "Semantical issues should address for actual use cases". Could you explain it to me?

Comment: @Jefffrey There aren't any semantical issues like _"But the semantic of `const RefContainer` is not the same as `const T&`"_ stated from the question, as far I can see. It's the OP's job to tell, if this actually a semantical issue (which I can't see from the question so far).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's a "semantical issue" for the language really. I would expect `RefContainer` to have reference semantic, but it does not if he follows your suggestion.

Comment: @Jefffrey _"It's a "semantical issue" for the language really."_ No, why? There certainly are valid use cases, and if not, shouldn't this be solved by the compiler, to forbid doing so?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Mainly because in C++ `T` and `const T` are supposed to be semantically different, with `const T`'s allowed actions being a subset of `T`'s in most cases. In this case both `RefContainer` and `const RefContainer` have exactly the same semantic and that's "act like a mutable reference". When you have a `const T` that acts like a mutable `Y`, then you have something wrong going on.

Comment: @Jefffrey This is of course the exact semantics of `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: @Jeffrey The semantics of `RefContainer<T> const` are the same as those of `T& const` which is the same as `T&`. The semantics of `T const&` are the same as those of `RefContainer<T const>`.

Comment: @T.C. Don't fall into the ["appeal to authority”](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/appeal-to-authority) fallacy.

Comment: @Oktalist "are the same as those of T& const which is the same as T&" No. The semantics of `T&` and `T const&` is deeply different.

Comment: @Jefffrey `T& const` (which can only happen via a typedef or template argument) and `T const&` are also deeply different.